# There are $9$ subsets of $[12]$, each one with $8$ elements and every element of $[12]$ appears $r$ times in the $9$ subsets. What's the value of $r$?

Tags: combinatorics

There are $9$ subsets of $[12]$, each one with $8$ elements and every element of $[12]$ appears **r** times in the $9$ subsets. What's the value of **r**?

If I have not made my self very clear. Here's an example of what needs to happen:

$[12]=\{0,1,2...,11\}$

If 1 element of $[12]$ appears twice in the $9$ subsets of then every other element of $[12]$ appears twice in the $9$ subsets

Comment: I just started college a month ago, so don't go too much on detail. I just would like to know how to think when faced with this kind of problems

Comment: Well, there are $72$ elements (counted with multiplicity) amongst your $9$ subsets so...

Comment: Still didn't get it :(

Comment: This is a standard technique.  Count the number of elements in your subsets in two different ways.  First way:  since each subset contains $8$ elements, the total is $9\times 8=72$.  Second:  since each integer in the set appears in exactly $r$ subsets, the total number of elements is $12\times r$,  Now solve for $r$.

Comment: Oh wow, how dumb I am ... Thanks alot dude.